# How to make to inline divs with text in them perfect squares

Tags: css

I have the code:

```
<div>C</div><div>A</div>

div{
            border: 4px solid Brown;
display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TKQzT/

So I end up with two rectangles with letters in them.

I was wanting them to display as squares instead. So currently they're rectangles taller than they are wide.

Does anyone know how to style them so they'll come out as perfect squares?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to set the display to `inline-block`, so that you can specify an explicit width and height:

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.25em;
    height: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TKQzT/13/

Comment: don't you just have to love `display: inline-block`? It almost always solves all my css problems somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

As letters are higher than wider, you'll have to set the with/height of the box manually.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be exact without giving them an equal width and height, but try:

```
div {
  border: 4px solid Brown;
  display: inline;
  padding:2px 5px;
  margin:1px
}
```

and if you're using `inline` just so you can line up the `div`'s side by side then I recommend using `float` and having the `div`'s not `inline`. This way you can give them a explicit `width` and `height`.

```
div {
  border: 4px solid Brown;
  padding:2px 5px;
  margin:1px; 
  float:left
}
```

See demo here: http://jsbin.com/ojumay/edit#html,live

Answer (score 0):

The better way i know to do it is to fix height and width, while using inline-block display to be able to do it.

Try this :

```
div{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    border: 4px solid Brown;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-align:center
}
​
```